# App crashing because of java.lang.String.trim() only when minifyEnabled is set to true

Tags: android

I am facing this problem only in the release version of the app where I got:

```
release {
    ...
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
}
```

the error I am getting is the following:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference

It has nothing to do with my code though, since it is working flawlessly in debug mode. I suspect it has something to do with the `minifyEnabled` or `shrinkResources`

I tried adding:

```
-keep class java.lang.String.** { *; }
```

to my ProGuard file, but that did not fix it.

What am I missing?

Comment: this is not a problem with String.trim() as the error says: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()'  **on a null object reference**. You need to check if the String is not null.

Comment: post your code and logcat here

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך but which string? it is working perfectly in debug mode, so it doesnt seam to be anything related to my code

Comment: Wherever you are getting the String from that you are trimming that's what needs keeping in your proguard (or a dependency of it).  Post your code.

Comment: like @CodeChimp says, the problem is not the String but the source of the string which is probably from a custom object.

Comment: Yeah after digging a little bit more, I noticed that the string comes from the custom object, although I don't want to exclude the whole custom object from proguard, wouldn't it be unsafe?

Comment: @Daniele How you solved this issue?